# Can we use external database in silverlight business application instead .mdf file

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Can we use external database in silverlight business application instead .mdf file? And if not how to observe database tables and records in mdf file?

Comment: Do you mean on the server-side or on the client-side?

Comment: As I'm beginner in silverlight I want to develop simple silverlight business application. But I dont want to use .mdf file as database which Domin context handles.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight does not have any straightforward direct db access feature. You'll have either:

- create a service (RIA service for instance)
- or use COM in elevated trust mode.

Both of which can potentially give you access to any db, not access dbs only.
RIA services can leverage linq to entity for which you'll find implementations for SQL server, Oracle...